# Auto Update list output in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation, list

I have an Excel sheet which uses a drop down list. When I update an item of this list (so I'm not adding anything, I'm just changing the name of the item that was already in the list) the old value still remains in the cell that contains the drop down list.

Right now I'm using Find & Replace to resolve this. Is there a way to automate this so it's more convenient for users that don't have this knowledge?

Edit:
To clarify I added some images.

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEh2a.png)

[After update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifoL5.png)

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: You are conflating data validation with the value in the cell. You have a list you use to perform data validation on user input.  You change the rules and assume that in some way affects the value in the cell. **Original validation list:** {"John", "Sally", "Beth"}  **Original Value entered:** "Sally"   **New validation list:** {"John", "Beth", "Mark", "Ingrid"} **Existing Value:** "Sally"  `triggers validation error`

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now. I'm trying to use the list feature in a way that it isn't meant to be used, right? Excel 'protects' the choice the user made and that decision can't be changed by updating the list on the background.

It does still raise the question how I should deal with changes though. So in your example, what if I decide that I want to add the surname as well? Updating all cells that contain a list manually takes forever as there are many entries.

Comment: This is getting too much for a comment.  Let me try to provide an Answer for you.

Comment: Do you have a sample?

Comment: I added two images to explain what I mean